# How can I perform a conditional join in mssql?

Tags: sql-server

I want to join a table to one of two possible tables, depending on data.  Here's an attempt that did not work, but gets the idea across, I hope.  Also, this is a mocked up example that may not be very realistic, so don't get too hung up on the idea this is representing real students and classes.

```
SELECT *
FROM
student
INNER JOIN class ON class.student_id = student.student_id
CASE
    WHEN class.complete=0
    THEN RIGHT OUTER JOIN report ON report.label_id = inprogress.class_id
    WHEN class.complete=1
    THEN RIGHT OUTER JOIN report ON report.label_id = completed.class_id
END
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That doesn't work because JOINs need to be consistent throughout the query.  If you need to join conditionally, then use WHERE clauses to simulate your joins, not JOIN statements.

Comment: Can you show an example of a right outer join in a where clause?  I am converting this from sybase where it had AND this.id =* that.id.

Comment: `WHERE (class.complete=0 AND report.label_id = inprogress.class_id) OR (class.complete=1 AND report.label_id = completed.class_id)`.  Of course, I don't think that's quite an outer join.

Comment: You probably want to look at sub-selects here, not joins.

Answer (score 9):

You have two join conditions and if either are true you want to commit a join - That's a boolean OR operation.

You simply need to:

```
RIGHT OUTER JOIN report ON (CONDITION1) OR (CONDITION2)
```

Let's unravel that a moment though, what is condition 1 and what is condition 2?

```
WHEN class.complete=0
THEN RIGHT OUTER JOIN report ON report.label_id = inprogress.class_id
WHEN class.complete=1
THEN RIGHT OUTER JOIN report ON report.label_id = completed.class_id
```

Here you're putting together two conditions on each of your condition 1 and 2, so your condition 1 is:

```
class.complete = 0 AND report.label_id = inprogress.class_id
```

and your condition 2 is

```
class.complete = 1 AND report.label_id = completed.class_id
```

So the completed SQL should be something like (and this is untested off the top of my head)

```
RIGHT OUTER JOIN report ON (
  class.complete = 0 AND report.label_id = inprogress.class_id
) OR (
  class.complete = 1 AND report.label_id = completed.class_id
)
```

---

### Worth mentioning..

I haven't run the above join but I know from experience the execution plan on that will be absolutely *abominable*, won't matter if performance isn't important and or your data set is small, but if the performance matters I *strongly* suggest you post a broader scope of what you want here and we can talk about a better approach to getting your particular data set that won't perform so terribly. I would personally write a join like above only as a last resort or if I was hacking something truly irrelevant.

Comment: To be completely certain - I don't know that you can even do an or of this nature because it switches the predicating table based on a conditional, so test it and let me know if SQL just complains at which point I'll delete this. The reason I don't know if you can is because as I say, this is *really terrible SQL* and as such I've never done such to my knowledge (I hope not anyway)

Comment: This appears to work, meaning no syntax errors.  Much appreciated! And this is updating a legacy system, so I think the performance will be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

try this (untested) -

```
SELECT *
FROM student S
    INNER JOIN class c ON c.student_id = S.student_id
    left outer join report ir on ir.label_id = inprogress.class_id AND c.complete=0
    left outer join report cr on cr.label_id = completed.class_id AND c.complete=1
```

Comment: Won't that give you two separate sets of result columns?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: yes, it would. Jimmy's solution is probably better

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join to either of 2 tables with reasonable performance, write a stored procedure for each path (one that joins table 1 to table A, one that joins table 1 to table B).  Make a third stored procedure that calls either the 1-A stored procedure or the 1-B stored procedure.  This way an efficient query plan will be performed in each case without having to make it recompile on each call or generate a strange query plan.

In your case, you actually want some records from *both* of the tables you might join to.  In that case, you want to union the results together rather than pick one or the other (and you can combine them in one sproc if you want to, it shouldn't hurt the query plan).  If you are sure the records won't duplicate between the two queries (it seems like they wouldn't), then as usual use UNION ALL for performance.